# Where can i find geoserver style for osm?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I'm trying to run an offline map using openlayers and geo server,i have import osm data to geo server containing:
    planet_osm_line 
    planet_osm_point
    planet_osm_polygon 
    planet_osm_roads

and from preview layer i can see the map succesfully;the problem is:
1.my polygon for iran doesn't have 2 state
2.how can i find a good sld style so my map look like the original openstreetmap

Comment: The answers in this [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70549/where-download-sld-styles-for-openstreetmap-for-geoserver) post might help you. Note, OSM does not use SLDs, so you will never get it identical.

Comment: thank you,I had seen this link before but yet not good enough :(

Comment: Well, Osm does not use SLD. So, I suspect you will have to make your own, using that as a basis.

Comment: I guess when I import data in geoserver it converts data to vector so...